# problem with connecting c++ libraries installed via homebrew macos m1

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I installed the libmemcached library via homebrew and it is located at the path

---

/**opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmemcached/**

---

but I cannot find it via cmake. I get a message about the absence of

---

**libmemcachedConfig.cmake**.

My thoughts:

As far as I understand cmake is looking for files, libraries and include in the

---

**/usr/local...,**

---

I made a symlink from **/opt/homebrew** to **/usr/local**, but nothing has changed. If I think homebrew has installed the library correctly, then the problem is in the file paths.

Comment: What is exact path to file `libmemcachedConfig.cmake` on your machine? Also, instead of *describing* the error message it is better to provide it exactly **as is**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough